# How do I copy values from one stack to another?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I am stuck after popping the values from stack1 then trying to push those values back into stack1, to later push back into stack2 in order. I'm not sure if I need another loop to make it nested loops or if I should switch to for loops as they are counting loops.

```
void copyStack(stack<int>& stack1, stack<int>& stack2)
{
   int size = stack1.size();
   while(size > 0)
   {
 
      stack2.push(stack1.top());
      stack1.pop();
      stack1.push(stack2.top());
      --size;
      
   }
   

}
```

Example:

Stack1: 4 3 2 1

Stack2: (empty)

(after running the function...)

Stack1: (empty)

Stack2: 4 3 2 1

Comment: Some values or all values? If the later, `std::stack` has a copy constructor.

Comment: @user4581301 All the values, I'm just trying to implement my own copy function, I do know stack has a swap() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, why don't you just use this:

```
void copyStack(stack<int>& stack1, stack<int>& stack2) {
    stack2 = stack1;
}
```

It's C++ ;)

Or, if you want to swap elements of these two stacks, instead of copying, you can use:

```
stack1.swap(stack2);
```

***EDIT***: if you want to do it by yourself and looking for an interesting solution, you can try these links:
[Clone a stack without extra space](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-a-stack-without-extra-space/)

[Clone a stack without using extra space | Set 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-a-stack-without-using-extra-space-set-2/?ref=rp)

Answer (score 2):

If you pop the values from one stack and push them onto another, they'll be in the reverse of their original order. You need an intermediate stack if you want them in the original order. Pop all values from `stack1` and push then to `stackTemp`, then do the same from `stackTemp` to `stack2`.

Comment: Thank you, but I had solved it with an extra stack already, I'm trying to implement the function without an intermediate stack.

Comment: @Jasmine I don't think this is possible without using an intermediate third container. At least not without using the protected `c` member. But if you ever need to use that member you are definitely using the wrong container.

Comment: @Jasmine You could use recursion, thereby implicitly using the call stack as the intermediate stack. But that would be a worse solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
void copy(Stack<T> source)
{
    Stack<T> temp1;
    Stack<T> temp2;

    while (!source.isEmpty())
    {
        temp1.push(source.peek());
        temp2.push(source.peek());
        source.pop();
    }
    while (!temp1.isEmpty())
    {
        push(temp1.peek());
        temp1.pop();
    }
    while (!temp2.isEmpty())
    {
        source.push(temp2.peek());
        temp2.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).